# Python module Folium - TypeError: module object is not callable

Tags: python, module, typeerror, heatmap, folium

I am currently working on a tutorial with the module "Folium" from the Leaflet-Library and want to integrate a heatmap.
Below, you can see my code for building a heatmap. I can't figure out why it gives me back the TypeError: 'Module' object is not callable. Are there any imports missing or can anybody help me out here with fixing this problem?

Thank you in advance! :)

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

myheatmap = folium.map(location=[48.774037, 9.174388], zoom_start=6)

mydata= {
    [48.774037, 9.174388, 0.1],
    [48.656556, 8.940168, 0.05]
}
HeatMap(mydata).add_to(myheatmap)
```

the error

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13864/2627038006.py in <module>
      4 
      5 #Startpunkt des Kartenausschnittes wählen
----> 6 myheatmap = folium.map(location=[48.774037, 9.174388], zoom_start=6)
      7 
      8 # Daten nach diesem Schema eingeben: Längengrad, Breitengrad, Wert für diesen Ort

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable```
````

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
myheatmap = folium.Map(location=[48.774037, 9.174388], zoom_start=6)
```

the 'M' in map should be Capitalized folium.***Map*** not folium.map